# Transferring data from SQl to Excel file

Tags: sql, excel

Getting this error message

```
User name not provided, either use -U to provide the user name
or use -T for Trusted Connection
```

on executing the following command:

```
EXEC [Procedure name], '[server name]', '[tablename]','[path of file]'
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Exec command is showing error message.How do I resolve it?

Comment: You're not authorized. You have to log in with a username and password

Comment: where should i add username and password, as this command doesn't accept these parameters

Comment: @Madeeha, I didn't ask for myself but for the community. Add the question to your... question!

Answer (score 0):

Save in csv format. and then open this file in excel and save in nessecary excel format

Comment: Saved in CSV format also,didn't work.Still showing same error message on executing the command :(

Comment: your answer is above from  Christian Cederquist. then save in csv.

Comment: where should i add username and password, as this command doesn't accept these parameters –